# My code skip the first condition check and GoTo next code, how can I fix it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data in Column A and B that may contain various data format ranging from letters, digits to special characters. I wrote the code as below, my data contains special characters.

```
Dim Sheet6 As Worksheet
Dim MyFilesPath As String
Dim cel As Range
Dim displaytext As String
Dim textmsg As String

            For Each cel In Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                If cel Like "*[!A-Za-z0-9]*" Then   'This line of code is skipped
                    cel.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    textmsg = "There is non-alphanumeric character in cell:"
                    displaytext = displaytext & vbCrLf & cel.Address
                Else
                    GoTo Savefile
                End If
                
            Next cel
            
                MsgBox textmsg & displaytext, vbCritical, "Please amend."
            
            Exit Sub
            
Savefile:
            Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells.ClearFormats
        
            Sheets("Sheet6").Copy
            ChDir MyFilesPath
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyFilesPath & "LIST_" & Format(CDate(Evaluate _
                ("WORKDAY(TODAY(), -1)")), "yyyymmdd") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
            
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

The outcome for data with special characters should be stopped with a msgbox but it didn't work, instead it jumped straight into 'Savefile' line. How can I fix this?

Comment: What's an example of a cell that should trigger that line?

Comment: Let's say Range("A1").Value = Happy^ , Range("B30").Value = Baby*/

Comment: just to be clear are you saying it skips that line or always goes to the evaluates to false so skips to the End if?

Comment: Why is your message box outside the loop?

Comment: @InjuredCoding Sorry my bad. When I debug the code, it does show it went through the line. So it evaluate as false and jump straight to else GoTo: Savefile

Comment: @SJR It's to prevent the Msgbox repeating at each cell address that contains special characters. It accumulates all cell addresses' hit into 1 Msgbox.

Comment: weird - seems to work fine for me with the eamples you gave.  try putting `test = cel.Value` just under the for each point it at a range that only contains those type of values and then step through the code with F8 checking what test is at each cel in the locals window.

Comment: The code you've posted suggests that once you go to savefile you don't return? I also can't replicate the issue.

Comment: @InjuredCoding I tried to debug it that way but it didn't work as well. Thank you for helping. CLR provided a fantastic solution to my problem.

Comment: @SJR Yes it just went straight to GoTo Savefile. Btw thanks for your help, CLR provided a fantastic solution below. :)

Comment: @JeffCh glad CLRs answer worked for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, but the issue you're describing (that the code doesn't pick up non-alphanumeric characters) is not re-creatable. It might be the use of `CurrentRegion` causing it to miss some cells that you're expecting it to highlight?

That said, your code does skip straight to Save immediately after finding its first compliant cell. I'd suggest a different method - something like this:

```
Dim MyFilesPath As String
Dim cel As Range
Dim displaytext As String
Dim textmsg As String

displaytext = ""
textmsg = "There is non-alphanumeric character in cell:"

For Each cel In Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If cel Like "*[!A-Za-z0-9]*" Then
        cel.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        displaytext = displaytext & vbCrLf & cel.Address
    End If
Next cel
                      
If displaytext = "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells.ClearFormats
    Sheets("Sheet6").Copy
    ChDir MyFilesPath
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyFilesPath & "LIST_" & Format(CDate(Evaluate _
    ("WORKDAY(TODAY(), -1)")), "yyyymmdd") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Else
    MsgBox textmsg & displaytext, vbCritical, "Please amend."
End If
```

Comment: Your codes worked like a charm. I seriously couldn't tell what went wrong in my code.  Closed all workbooks and tried my code on fresh sheet of manual data, it didn't work as well.. Thanks a bunch CLR!

Comment: I think the issue with yours is that provided one compliant cell is found, it will jump to the Save routine before advising there is an issue. With mine, every cell is tested first and Save routine only runs if no non-compliant cells were found.

Comment: To test if it is an issue with compliant cell,  I made some changes to my code: Remove `Else GoTo Savefile` , and then I ran the code, this time round it did display msgbox. But problem is, after I amended the cells with special characters, the msgbox still popped up without displaying any message.  By right it should save the file...  Is this part of compliant cell issue?

Comment: With your code, the save routine won't run unless you `GoTo` it. That will happen as soon as a compliant cell is found.

Comment: Thanks CLR, I understand better now. Have a good one! :)

Comment: I have a side question if you don't mind me asking.  Is there a proper VBA error handling for Run-time error when canceling a 'Save As' dialog displayed? (Sometimes I want to overwrite the saved file, sometimes I don't, thus the cancelling action. )